# Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library [ IIS and PHP ]

Tags: php, html, iis, sqlsrv

I'm currently doing a project for my school and I faced a few errors. I am currently using PHP 7.1.12 with IIS and I have these errors.

[Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_interbase.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_oci8_12c.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_pdo_oci.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih9LZ.png)

I checked my php.ini and I added those dlls above into the extensions part. I also checked my php\ext file and I do have those dll files.

[As you can see from the highlighted files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WhXl.png)
[My php.ini file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTfqC.png)

I tried googling for answers but most people use Apache instead of IIS. Anyone knows how to solve it ? Your help is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Those are database extensions.  If you are not using those types of databases then you can go ahead and comment them out for the time being with a ';'.

Typically for school projects students use:

> MySQL (listed in php.ini as: 'php_pdo_mysql.dll'),

or

> Microsoft SQL Server (listed in php.ini as: 'php_pdo_odbc.dll')...

...database adapter files (aka pdo .dll's).  Sorry I am late to the *game* in answering this question since no one else felt compelled to do so in almost two months.  I hope you were able to figure this out from a teacher or another fellow student since it appears I am probably far too late to be of much help to you!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply ! Somehow I've managed to solved the error a while back, but thank you for responding !